# Hide submenu of Revisioning-module

Tags: routes

I would like to hide the items marked in the image. But as it turns out, they aren't stored an Array as we are used to in Drupal (at least as far as I can see).
How can I unset or hide them. Hiding by using CSS isn't an option.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you use drupal 6 or 7

You can configure this:

- go to:  http:/your.drupal/admin/user/permissions
- CTR + F do search on page and search for this both permissions:
- unpublish current revision
- delete archived revisions

But if also admins should not see this any more, you have to modify code:
(here for Drupal 6)

- edit sites/all/modules/revisioning/revisioning_theme.inc
- search for: unpublish current revision
- 4 rows below you will see:  `$links[] = $link;`
- change it to: `// $links[] = $link;`
- now search for: delete archived revisions and do the same
- save and done

Comment: Ok, great. Thanks. Any thought about Drupal 7?

Comment: Never, never hack at contributed modules/core code. Your site will likely break the next time an update comes around. You can handle this easily with a `hook_menu_alter` implementation, in which you would change the `access callback` function for the menu items in question to a custom one, or simply to `FALSE`.

Answer (score 1):

For drupal 7 it is the same:

you can configurate it here also for all user
http:/your.drupal/admin/people/permissions

> Delete content revisions
>
> Revert content revisions
>
> Publish content revisions (of anyone's content)
>
> Unpublish current revision (of anyone's content)

in code it is in:
sites/all/modules/moduleS/revisioning/revisioning_theme.inc
_revisioning_generate_node_links_according_to_permissions()
there you will find serveral lines like:

`$themed_links[] = l(t('Publish'), "node/$nid/revisions/$node->vid/publish");`

to deactivate: place // in front of them,
but i would suggest to use the config options if possible.

If you have to sue the code version, use git versioning with a pristine branch, you you will further be able to update the software, withput loosing your changes

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I do need the permissions, but not the display...

Comment: any idea how to do this without deleting the permissions?